# How do I set a subdomain like mail.v2techlabs.com where I can directly access my email

Tags: email, shared-hosting

I am using iPage shared hosting. I want to access my emails at URLs like `mail.xyz.com` where I can directly login to my email. Right now it is going to the iPage website and logs in from there.

Can you please let me know how to set this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to setup access to a web application for email, commonly referred to as [Webmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webmail), for your domain.

The subdomain `mail.abccompany.com` is often used as the name of mail servers, which  sends out or receives email. More often the subdomain used to *access* Webmail is simply: `webmail.abccompany.com`, and a CNAME record in the domain's DNS tables is created for that.

Most web hosting packages that include email offer Webmail access, and if the web hosting company you're referring to is `ipage.com`, then it appears they do as well: [iPage Features](http://www.ipage.com/hosting-features)

However, since you're using shared hosting, you likely won't have access to install or configure server applications like Webmail yourself, and therefore will be limited to what they provide. Therefore, I would suggest contacting their tech support to confirm if you can forward your Webmail access to a subdomain and to assist you further.

Otherwise, if this is critical to you, I would suggest finding a different web hosting company that offers that (those using control panels like cPanel or Plesk would), or looking into VPS and dedicated servers, where you have much more control over server applications and configurations.

Comment: Actually I talked to the support and figured out that it was not possible to get what I wanted. However what  I did is that I created a subdomain and kept a simple html with the login form present on the ipage website. So the user now sees it as a customised login page where I can put the company logo etc. However it goes to the same webmail, but it solves the problem for now.

Comment: Any suggestions for good VPS providers? Also the price will be a huge factor for me right now as I am just in the planning phase of a huge web application.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you might want to move to a VPS, and would suggest one that uses cPanel or Plesk to help make server management easier (account setup is pretty automated with those). I can't really recommend web hosting companies, but can suggest googling "web host" or "VPS" comparison sites. Just be aware that some of the reviews there are not always impartial...but it will give your some product details and pricing options to compare with. Good luck!